# Accessing $(this) in GopherJS

Tags: jquery, this, gopherjs

As an exercise, I'm converting a [single page application](https://tutorialzine.com/2015/02/single-page-app-without-a-framework) from JavaScript to GopherJS.

In the JS code, the following appears:

```
var list = $('.all-products .products-list');
list.find('li').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var productIndex = $(this).data('index');
  window.location.hash = 'product/' + productIndex;
})
```

In my GopherJS conversion, I have the following:

```
list := jquery.NewJQuery(".all-products .products-list")
list.Find("li").On("click", func(e jquery.Event) {
e.PreventDefault()
// productIndex := jquery.NewJQuery(e.Target).Data("index").(float64)
// dom.GetWindow().Location().Hash = "product/" + productIndex
})
```

but I'm struggling to figure out how to translate `$(this)`. The `jquery.NewJQuery(e.Target)` does not seem to return the `li`, but a `div` that is inside the `li`.

My understanding is that `$(this)` inside a function returns the `this` scoped to the outer jQuery item (`li`).

Comment: Yes, but how do I do that in GopherJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `$(this)` you'd need to use js.MakeFunc to get access to the `this` object.  Something along the lines of

```
list.Find("li").On("click", js.MakeFunc(func(this *js.Object, args []*js.Object) interface{} {
    e := dom.WrapEvent(args[0])
    e.PreventDefault()
    productIndex := jquery.NewJQuery(this).Data("index").(float64)
    dom.GetWindow().Location().Hash = "product/" + productIndex
    return nil
}))
```

Comment: I suspected as much. I just was not sure what I would do with the `args` parameter. Thanks.